# MDX - COUNT ( TOPPERCENT () ) returns 1 when no value

Tags: count, mdx

We wrote this MDX query:

```
COUNT(
   TOPPERCENT(
      {[d_gca].[h_gca].[l_gca].MEMBERS}, 
     80,  
    [Measures].[m_invoice_item_amount] 
   )
 )
```

The problem is, when there is no value for `[d_gac].[h_gac].[l_gac].MEMBERS`, the displayed result is always 1.

Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Can you just wrap the inner set in the `NonEmpty` function?

```
COUNT(
   TOPPERCENT(
      NONEMPTY(
        {[d_gca].[h_gca].[l_gca].MEMBERS}
        ,[Measures].[m_invoice_item_amount]
     ), 
     80,  
    [Measures].[m_invoice_item_amount] 
   )
 )
```

Comment: I'm working with a data viz framework and this brings a unknown error. This was an hypothesis, did'nt know how to syntax it. Long processing time btw. Anyway to set default value to 0 if empty ?

Comment: @Alsib to set default to 0 if empty sounds very dangerous - it is all the null space in the cube that makes it fast - if you replace nulls with 0s you might find things slowing down